# ConTeXt for non-technical person

Tags: context, editors

A dear person to me has started her own small publishing company (psychology related books -- completely non-technical) and she uses Microsoft Word. It's a one woman operation and she often asks me for help with editing. I have the idea to get her to try to use LaTeX or ConTeXt rather than Word. However, she is not a technical person. Since I spend so much time helping her anyway, I was considering asking her to use LyX for editing and then I would make necessary changes in LaTeX to get the formatting that she wants. Hopefully I could eventually teach her how to do my end of that work, but that might be a pipe dream. However, I've read that ConTeXt might be a good option too. Perhaps that would be easier for a non-technical person to learn than LaTeX or just better for non-technical books (-- your thoughts appreciated).

Is there an editor (available in Windows) for ConTeXt created with non-technical users in mind?

Comment: I've never never understood/fancied LyX. I think everyone can understand how it —the *raw* code, without LyX— works; you still need to convince them, of course. Don't show her a document full of commands, show her the most minimallistic document, just a bunch of paragraphs (as usual, separated with a blank line) and *one* sentence in *one* paragraph italicized (with `\emph{…}` for instance). That way she absolutely understands how it works and how easy is to use commands. I remember when I started, I was shown full mathematical papers and I understood nothing (I had never seen “code”).

Comment: I said `\emph` but I just wanted to show a command, I did not mean to teach her LaTeX (in fact ConTeXt may easily fit her needs).

Comment: Alternatively, she may be as well off to use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) for content and organization, and you can do the LaTeX conversion yourself (or set her up a Makefile or similar script to do it).

Comment: I think your friend should at first think about her wishes and expectation for the development of her business. Does she like the editing part or does she hope that sometime in the feature she can outsource this job? Also without more informations about the type of documents she produce it is quite difficult to recommend a suitable tool.

Comment: The book is a typical book. It has front matter, including table of contents, then chapters, with the occasional graphic, then end matter, including endnotes, index and bibliography. I've been also considering if InDesign might be a better option than any TeX, as it might be easier for a layperson to learn, but it's hard to frame that question in a TeX QA site. She wants to learn as much as possible, but frankly, she only just got used to using Word, and yet I'm trying to dissuade Word. :\. It's tougher for some to learn new things on the computer than for others.

Comment: If her skills lays somewhere else she should outsource the computer and publishing part and concentrate on the content. There are already too many bad looking books on the market. Then she can use for the writing whatever tool she likes and will have to learn only a bit of markup for headers, cites etc.

Comment: If she is not the technical person, then I would really suggest LaTeX over conTeXt. 1) Community behind LaTeX is much bigger; 2) Documentation of LaTeX is much more complete.

Comment: Could she use XML? ConTeXt can typeset XML files, so she could use something like XMLmind or oXygen to author, then you could work with her to develop a stylesheet in ConTeXt. You'd gain validation facilities from XML, but still get the control of ConTeXt.

Comment: @NobbZ: With those exact same arguments, she should stick to Word, right?

Answer (score 3):

My set of recommendations is this:

1. **Teach your friend to write *[Markdown](http://commmonmark.org/)*.**

   - She can do so even in MS Word: there is a plugin called [Writage](http://www.writage.com/) which makes it easier for people used to Word.
   - There are also other Markdown editors available (some being implemented in JavaScripts and directly running in browser windows providing a live-rendered HTML preview -- like you see on this very website!)
   - There are only about a dozen Markdown rules that already let you cover 90% of typical formatting needs. I've successfully trained (non-technical!) people in the past to use Markdown within 30 minutes and they were able to run. (Well, from time to time they called back and asked *"How do I do XYZ? How do I do ABC?"*...)
2. **Use *[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)* to convert the Markdown to LaTeX or ConTeXt** and finally, PDF (or even HTML, EPUB/EPUB3, OpenDocument, DOCX, MediaWiki, DokuWiki...).
3. **Write a Makefile (or a Batch file) for her so she can fast preview intermediate results herself.** You'll have to experiment which output format fits best for her needs, and which exact set of Pandoc command line parameters to apply.
4. **Take the ConTeXt or LaTeX output from her and do your thing...**

---

This set of recommendations root in my own personal experience: as a non-TeXnical person (*who knew about (La)TeX before, but never wanted to start climbing up the steep slope of learning it!*) I'm now learning one or the other LaTeX trickery too (while still authoring most of my texts in Markdown). Without Pandoc+Markdown this would never have happened....